# While running application by IDEA Android Studio virtual device is not launched

Tags: ide, emulator, android-studio

I have created blank full screen application using Android Studio. When I run the app I select predefined virtual device than nothing happens. IDE just waits. Please look at the screenshot please.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try installing **HAXM** . I too had the same problem and installing HAXM did solve it. [check the Link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows)

Do check the prerequisites for your system.